# How to replace different words in a text with a unique value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to replace many words (or phrases) with the same value in an text using RegExp() javascript function. It replaces singular words with the correct values but when it have to replace a phrase that contains the same word, it's not working (Idk how would it work).

In my text, for example I want to replace *activity* and *Weekly activity minutes* with the same value:

> "The activity patient correspond to Weekly activity minutes"

But it's just replacing *activity*

**How I'm doing it:**

I have a **keywords.js** file where I get all the phrases inside an object structured like this:

```
let keywords: {
    "activity": {
        phrases: ['activity']
    },
    "sleep": {
        phrases: ['sleep']
    }
}
```

and in my javascript section in my html:

```
@section('javascript')
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{{ asset("js/keywords.js") }}"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
       @if($patient)
          let patient = {
              weight: 60,
              height: 70,
              'currents' : {
                  "activity" : 100,
                  "sleep" : 60
              },
          }
          let t = $("#text-section-article").html(t); //the text where i want to look for word/phrases

          Object.entries(keywords).forEach(([key, values])=>{
          //Im iterating all over the keywords words
              Object.entries(values).forEach(([phraseKey, phraseValue])=>{
              //Im iterating all over the phrases
                  if(patient.currents.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                  //If my patient have activity in my object 'currents' I put a tooltip to that word in my body text by replacing it in this way.
                  title = `Your current ${phraseValue} is ${patient.currents[key]}`; //Your current activity is 100
                  t = t.replace(new RegExp(key, 'gi'), '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="' + title + '" class="tip ' + phraseValue + '">' + phraseValue + '</span>');
                  }
              });       
       });
       $("#text-section-article").html(t);
       @endif
    });
    </script>
@endsection
```

In this case in my article text all *activity* words now have a tooltip showing its current value.

What I want to do is *add* more words and phrases to my keywords object in this way:

```
let keywords: {
    "activity": {
        phrases: ['activity', 'Weekly activity minutes']
    },
    "sleep": {
        phrases: ['sleep', 'Sleep minutes']
    }
}
```

to replace all those phrases (if they exists) in my article text with the same value of patient object.

I'm having a bad time with this and I'll appreciate so much if you help me in find a way to manage all I've described and if there's a simple/better way to handle it just let me know.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Hi interesting questino, perhaps iterate over the phrases in the list, and modify the resulting string?

Comment: `Weekly activity minutes` should go first, or `activity` would be replaced before that.

Comment: Hi, here is a jsfiddle if you want to check a little: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy4awpe6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do with regexp, but you can do the next:

First, you need to sort phrases from the longest to the shortest. This way you first collect all the phrases that may contain shorter ones. So if you have

```
['activity', 'Weekly activity']
```

it should become

```
['Weekly activity', 'activity']
```

Then, you need to split the original string into an array so you could iterate and look for phrases.

```
['The', 'activity', 'patient', 'is', 'correspond', 'to', 'Weekly', 'activity', 'minutes']
```

The idea would be to transform the original array to this:

```
['The', 'activity', 'patient', 'is', 'correspond', 'to', 'Weekly activity minutes']
```

Where we no longer have separate words, but phrases. While looking for those phrases you should also record the index where the phrase can be found in the result array.

At this point, all you need to do is to iterate through the result array, check if you have recorded the index for the current phrase, and if so, you wrap it with a `<span>` element, if not you just skip it. The last step will be to join every phrase in the result into a string.

Here's the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tara5/43gcz0mx/

It's a bit rough, the phrase searching can be optimized to reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll check it deeply later but it seems the exactly what I'm looking for, maybe It'll get weird when the article would be long and it'd containg many words. I'll let you know :)